# Как закрепить полукруг внизу страницы

Tags: html, css

Нужно закрепить внизу страницы полукруг, при этом страница не должна листаться.
Как на скриншоте. Но проблема в том ,Что при разных разрешениях этот самый полукруг, то уезжает, то вообще пропадает с экрана.
Пробовал различные варианты для footer, но они не подходят для моего случая т.к у меня происходит смещение полукруга или он вообще пропадает

```css
   .radius {
    height: 38%;

 background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="rgba(203, 226, 239)"/></svg>') 0 0 / cover no-repeat;

    margin: 15% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="radius"></div>
```

Сделал вот так, но теперь полукруг слишком сильно вылез, должна быть лишь его половина

```css
   .radius {


 background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="rgba(203, 226, 239)"/></svg>') 0 0 / cover no-repeat;

    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="radius"></footer>
```

Если убрать  height: 100%; и вписать  widght: 100%; , то полукруг пропадает вообще.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам обязателен svg? Или можно через css?

Comment: можно и через css, на сайте прочитал ,что лучше через svg, но это значения не имеет

Comment: по моему так красивее : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rbzgKw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример кода с div.
Полукруг 38% от экрана в высоту:

```css
.radius {
    height: 76vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #cbe2ef;
    bottom: -38vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="radius"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, полукруг на разных устройствах немного деформируется, но всегда есть на экране

Comment: @Men  у полукруга должно быть всегда соотношение 1 к 2, где в вашем случае высота = 1, ширина = 2. Иначе говоря 38% - высоты * 2. Это чисто с геометрической точки зрения, если же вы хотите «подровнять» полукруг к разным версиям экранов, то используйте медиа-запросы. Ваш svg в вашей задаче не загрузился, закачайте его куда-нибудь и вставьте нормально. Посмотрим еще раз, с свг.